# Batch: Move all files from multiple subfolders (same name) into the parent

Tags: batch-file

I've just started working with Batch-Files and ran into a problem.
I need to move all files from multiple folders with the same name (old) into the parent.
This worked fine if I only do it for 1 folder but I can't figure out how to do it for multiple folders simultaneously. I'd appreciate some help. Here my folder structure:

- Folder\1\old\somefiles => Folder\1\somefiles
- Folder\2\old\somefiles => Folder\2\somefiles
- Folder\3\old\somefiles => Folder\3\somefiles

Here my Code for one folder:

```
for %%F in ( c:\test\folder\120006\old\*.*) do move /Y %%F c:\test\folder\120006
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: `for %%F in ("C:\test\folder\120006\old\*.*") do move /Y "%%~F" "%%~dpF.."` (the `~dp` modifier returns the full path to the parent directory of the file, and `..` goes one level up)

Comment: @aschipfl that does not work recursively.

Comment: My comment suggested a way to avoid having to specify the target as a constant, but nothing else; sorry for being unclear! For what you need do this: `for /D %%D in ("C:\test\folder\*") do for %%F in ("%%~D\old\*.*") do move /Y "%%~F" "%%~dpF.."`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it seems the files to process as well as the changing directories are always on the same respective directory hierarchy level, the following code should do what you expect:

```cmd
rem // Iterate over the changing directories:
for /D %%D in ("C:\test\folder\*") do (
    rem // Iterate over the files to process:
    for %%F in ("%%~D\old\*.*") do (
        rem // Actually move the files one level up:
        move /Y "%%~F" "%%~dpF.."
    )
)
```

I would not use recursion (`for /R`) unless it was really needed.

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly. Can you show me how I can only let certain (not all) files be moved? They should only be moved if there aren't any files in the parent folder yet. @aschipfl

Comment: You could do `dir /A:-D > nul 2>&1 && move /Y "%%~F" "%%~dpF.."` (the `dir` command returns an error in case no files (`/A:-D`) are found; `> nul 2>&1` suppresses any output of `dir`; `&&` lets the following command execute only in case of no error)

Comment: I tried it like this but it didn't work. Any ideas? @aschipfl `rem // Iterate over the changing directories:
for /D %%D in ("C:\test\folder\*") do (
    rem // Iterate over the files to process:
    for %%F in ("%%~D\old\*.*") do (
        rem // Actually move the files one level up:
        dir /A:-D > nul 2>&1 && move /Y "%%~F" "%%~dpF.."
    )
)`

Comment: You need to provide a path for `dir`, like this: `dir /A:-D "%%~D"` (I missed that in my former comment, sorry!)

Comment: This is just a link to the [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51542843)...

Answer (score 0):

On the cmd line use:

```
 for /r X:\Folder /d %F in (old.?) do @move "%F\*" "%~dpF"
```

In a batch file:

```
@Echo off
for /r X:\Folder /d %%F in (old.?) do move "%%F\*" "%%~dpF"
```

Sample tree on my ramdrive before:

```
> tree /F
Auflistung der Ordnerpfade für Volume RamDisk
└───Folder
    ├───1
    │   └───old
    │           somefiles
    ├───2
    │   └───old
    │           somefiles
    └───3
        └───old
                somefiles
```

And after running the commands:

```
> tree /f
Auflistung der Ordnerpfade für Volume RamDisk
└───Folder
    ├───1
    │   │   somefiles
    │   └───old
    ├───2
    │   │   somefiles
    │   └───old
    └───3
        │   somefiles
        └───old
```

If there ***are*** any other folders named `OLD` in the tree beneath `Folder` whose files should **not** be moved one level up - use aschipl's solution, otherwise **I** prefer the more simple solution.