# move all files from "old" folders out into the parent as long as there are no files existing in the parent folder yet

Tags: batch-file

My code should move all files from "old" folders out into the parent as long as there are no files existing in the parent folder yet.

```
└───Folder
    ├───1
    │   └───old
    │           somefiles
    ├───2
    │   └───old
    │           somefiles
    └───3
        └───old
                somefiles

└───Folder
    ├───1
    │   │   somefiles
    │   └───old
    ├───2
    │   │   somefiles
    │   └───old
    └───3
        │   somefiles
        └───old
```

My code so far moves 1 file out to the parent (if there are no files there yet) and after that it stops because there is now an existing file in the parent.

```
rem // Iterate over the changing directories:
for /D %%D in ("C:\testen\qft\*") do (
    rem // Iterate over the files to process:
    for %%F in ("%%~D\old\*.*") do (
        rem // Actually move the files one level up:
        dir /A:-D "%%~D" ||  move /Y "%%~F" "%%~dpF.."
    )
)
```

I tried to solve the problem like this:

```
rem // Iterate over the changing directories:
for /D %%D in ("C:\testen\qft\*") do (
    rem // Iterate over the files to process:
    for %%F in ("%%~D\old\*.*") do (
        rem // Actually move the files one level up:
    dir /A:-D "%%~D" || set VAR="true"
    if "%VAR%" == "true" (
    move /Y "%%~F" "%%~dpF.."
    dir /A:-D "%%~F" || set VAR="false"
    )
    )
)
```

but I must have some mistake left in my code adjustment because it no longer works correctly. Can someone see my mistake(s)?

Comment: Seems this is a follow-up question of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51517094)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems in your attempt:

1. you need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) for the variable `VAR` as you are writing and reading it in the same block of code; if you change it to `set "VAR=true"` and `set "VAR="` (empty), you could use `if defined VAR`, which does not require delayed expansion;
2. the content of the currently iterated directory should not be checked in the inner `for` loop, so this is skipped in case there are already files;

Here is a possible solution:

```cmd
rem // Iterate over the changing directories:
for /D %%D in ("C:\testen\qft\*") do (
    rem // Check whether current directory contains files:
    dir /A:-D "%%~D\*.*" > nul 2>&1 || (
        rem // Iterate over the files to process:
        for %%F in ("%%~D\old\*.*") do (
            rem // Actually move the files one level up:
            move /Y "%%~F" "%%~dpF.."
        )
    )
)
```