# Batch copy one mp3-file to its parent directory and rename it

Tags: batch-file, copy

I have to copy one mp3-file from it's subfolder to its parent folder and then rename it, e.g. `NEW_originalfilename.mp3`. There are lots of mp3s within each subfolder, but it doesn't matter which one is copied. Can be the first one.

E.g.

```
folder1/sub1/one.mp3
folder1/sub1/two.mp3
folder1/sub1/three.mp3
folder1/sub2/more1.mp3
folder1/sub2/more2.mp3
folder2/sub1/aaa.mp3
folder2/sub1/bbb.mp3
folder2/sub2/111.mp3
folder2/sub2/222.mp3
folder2/sub2/333.mp3
```

Result:

```
folder1/NEW_one.mp3
folder1/NEW_more1.mp3
folder2/NEW_aaa.mp3
folder1/NEW_111.mp3
```

Is there a batch windows solution?

Comment: @colidyre I surely answered myself similar questions, but your reference is tagged bash not batch-file.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @ECHO OFF
 
    SETLOCAL
 
    SET parent="C:\Users\Ubuntu\Desktop\TestMix"
 
    CD /d %parent% 
 
    FOR /r %parent% %%d IN (*.mp3) DO XCOPY "%%d" %parent%
 
    ECHO Done. Press any key to terminate script.
 
    PAUSE >NUL

Comment: This batch works fine, but the "XCOPY "%%d" %parent%" should be dynamic, so the files should be copied the refered subfolder and not to main parent folder

Comment: @Letterman I think you need to Enable delayedexpension, use: 
`setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`
and use "!" instead of "%" with your variable parent in the loop

Comment: @Letterman: It could be a nice idea to move your code from the comments to the answer. I suggest to format it like I edited your folder descriptions (as code).

Comment: Essentially what you are trying to do is move a file up one level.  I think your terminology is a little off.  The parent folder would be the folder the file is in.  So the folder you wan to move it to would be the grandparent folder.  Lot's of answers on SO that do that already. This question is probably almost asked weekly.  I will find a few of the previous questions for you.  Here is one from just a few days ago. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51593698/batch-move-files-from-different-subfolder-up-one-level-respectively